# why are my images getting cropped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using the [iosslider](http://iosscripts.com/iosslider/) script which works great but I can't figure out why it's cropping my images instead of resizing them.  Here are my css style and jquery call:

CSS:

```
.iosSlider {
/* required */
position: relative;
top: 0;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;

width: 100%;
height: 300px;
}


.iosSlider .slider {
/* required */
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
}


.iosSlider .slider .slide {
/* required */
float: left;
}
```

My jQuery Call:

```
$('.iosSlider').iosSlider({
        snapToChildren: true,
        desktopClickDrag: true,
        keyboardControls: true,
        onSlideChange: slideChange
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class = 'iosSlider'>   
    <div class = 'slider'>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="/some_img_1.png" />
        </div>
                <div class="item">
            <img src="/some_img_2.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea why I can't get my images to resize to a height of 300px?  The originals are 600px high so they are being cut in half. I'm sure it's a CSS issue but I can't seem to track it down.  Any thoughts?

Comment: One thing I have noted in your HTML is that, you have not used class ".slide", which is present in your CSS. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS rules are only applying a height to the divs that contain the images. If you want the images to be sized to 300px tall, add a rule like:

```
.iosSlider .slider .item img {
   height: 300px;
   width: auto;
}
```